# Sorting a JSON object with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, sorting

I have the following json object and I'm trying to sort it by price.

```
var data = {"PROPERTY":[
  {"PRICE":456,"NAME":"Test Property 1"},
  {"PRICE":789,"NAME":"Test Property 2"},
  {"PRICE":123,"NAME":"Test Property 3"},
  {"PRICE":654,"NAME":"Test Property 4"},
  {"PRICE":125,"NAME":"Test Property 5"}
]}
```

Here is the code i'm using to sort.

```
data.sort(sortByProperty('PRICE'));    

function sortByProperty(property) {
                'use strict';
                return function (a, b) {
                    var sortStatus = 0;
                    if (a[property] < b[property]) {
                        sortStatus = -1;
                    } else if (a[property] > b[property]) {
                        sortStatus = 1;
                    }

                    return sortStatus;
                };
            }
```

Needless to say the sort is not working. Is it because of the property attribute?

Comment: No, it's because `data` object has no `sort` method.

Comment: Indeed, @ElmoVanKielmo hit it. You'd need to call `data.PROPERTY.sort(...)`

Comment: Similar question asked before. See below.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects

Comment: @Blaise - the question you linked has no wrapper object containing the list - and actually this wrapper causes the issue here. OP has prepared the comparison function correctly, so your link will not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` object has no `sort` method - change one line to this:

```
data['PROPERTY'].sort(sortByProperty('PRICE'));
```

And the fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gFq95/)